# One picture belonging different galleries?

Tags: images, attachments, gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

How can one picture belongs different galleries?

For example, there are two galleries. I want to avoid loading the image twice (in two galleries) but it shown (included) in the first and second gallery.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in NextGen gallery.

You have to upload the image into each folder, as NextGen gallery works with file structures, not with database entries for retrieving the images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `include` attribute of the `[gallery]` shortcode to include the images in your galleries. For example, if you have an image with ID of 6 and you want to include it in two different galleries and in different posts, in the first post you can put:

```
[gallery include="1,2,31,6"]
```

This include images with IDs: 1, 2 31, and 6. And on the second post:

```
[gallery include="7,12,35,6"]
```

This include images 7, 12, 45 and 6.

As of WP 3.5, the `ids` attribute is included by default in the gallery shortcode, which give you much flexibility in choosing and manipulating images in your galleries, read more in the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode).

Comment: This should work fine for WordPress Galleries, @Ahmad M, but for the NextGen Gallery this is not usable.

Comment: @fischi Thanks, it was not clear on the question, just now I saw the <plugin-nextgen-gallery> tag.